# JSTL forEach loop optimal way of next index value

Tags: jsp, jstl

I have a request headers map where one of the header key value contains again a string as below shown example.

```
headerkey = abc=227,de_f=AE,ghf=ABCD,ijk=25.25,lmn=55.28,opq=GMT+4,rst=AS,uvw=vhigh,xyz=5000
```

Now I want to fetch only the **de_f** value i.e **`AE`** in an optimized loop condition

> `<c:forEach var="nextHeader" items="${header}"> <c:if test =
>   "${nextHeader.key == 'headerkey'}"> <c:set var="headerkeystring"
>   value="${nextHeader.value}"/> <c:set var="splitstring"
>   value="${fn:split(headerkeystring, ',')}" /> <c:forEach var="i"
>   items="${splitstring}"> <c:set var="subsplit" value="${fn:split(i,
>   '=')}" /> <c:forEach var="k" items="${subsplit}"> <c:if test = "${k ==
>   'de_f'}"> <c:out value="${k + 1}" />  <!-- Expecting here to print
>   "AE" --> </c:if> </c:forEach> </c:forEach> </c:if> </c:forEach>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the inner **c:forEach** and **c:out** as shown below that should give your result

```
<c:forEach var="k" items="${subsplit}" varStatus="status">
<c:if test = "${k == 'de_f'}">
<c:out value="${subsplit[status.index+1]}" /> <!-- This Should print "AE" -->
</c:if>
</c:forEach>
```